# Passing generic type from one class to another?

Tags: java, rest, generics

This is more a question of generics and how to extend the child class to use a type defined.

I have a class APIResponse to which I define the type of data passed via generics, this class also stores other details such as messages, errors that I want to pass to the UI invoking the REST service.

I get a errror when I try to create an instance of APIResponseEntity with the type specified. I might not be using generics correctly here, please can you tell me how to pass the type of data returned into APIResponseEntity that can ultimately be used in APIResponse.

```
public class APIResponseEntity<T> extends ResponseEntity<APIResponse<T>> {


public APIResponseEntity(HttpStatus pStatusCode) {
    super(pStatusCode);
}

public APIResponseEntity(HttpStatus pStatusCode, MultiValueMap<String, String> pHeaders) {
    super(pHeaders, pStatusCode);
}

public APIResponseEntity(HttpStatus pStatusCode, APIResponse<T> pBody) {
    super(pBody, pStatusCode);
}

public APIResponseEntity(HttpStatus pStatusCode, APIResponse<T> pBody, MultiValueMap<String, String> pHeaders) {
    super(pBody, pHeaders, pStatusCode);
}
```

}

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "status", "error", "data", "messages" })
public final class APIResponse<T> {


private APIResponseStatus _status;

private T _data;

private APIError _error;

private List<APIMessage> _messages;


public APIResponse() {
    super();
    _messages = new ArrayList<>();
}

public APIResponse(T pData) {
    this();
    _status = APIResponseStatus.OK;
    _data = pData;
}

public APIResponse(APIError pError) {
    this();
    _status = APIResponseStatus.ERROR;
    _error = pError;
}


public APIResponseStatus getStatus() {
    return _status;
}

public void setStatus(APIResponseStatus pStatus) {
    _status = pStatus;
}

public Object getData() {
    return _data;
}

public void setData(T pData) {
    _data = pData;
}

public APIError getError() {
    return _error;
}

public void setError(APIError pError) {
    _error = pError;
}

public List<APIMessage> getMessages() {
    return _messages;
}

public void setMessages(List<APIMessage> pMessages) {
    _messages = pMessages;
}

private void addMessage(APIMessageStatus pMessageStatus, String pMessage) {
    _messages.add(new APIMessage(pMessageStatus, pMessage));
}

public void addMessageInfo(String pMessage) {
    addMessage(APIMessageStatus.INFO, pMessage);
}

public void addMessageWarning(String pMessage) {
    addMessage(APIMessageStatus.WARNING, pMessage);
}

public void addMessageError(String pMessage) {
    addMessage(APIMessageStatus.ERROR, pMessage);
}
```

I am getting a compilation error when I try to create a APIResponseEntity object with generics

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/banks", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public APIResponseEntity<List<Bank>> getBanks(WebRequest pWebRequest) {

    IUser user = getUser(pWebRequest);
    BankCriteria criteria = new BankCriteria();
    List<Bank> banks= _bankService.getBanks(user, criteria);
    APIResponse<List<Bank>> response = new APIResponse<>(banks);
    APIResponseEntity<List<Bank>> entity =  new APIResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK, banks); // errror , cannot infer type arguments for APIResponseEntity
    return entity;

}
```

Comment: Is that `ResponseEntity` from Spring framework? Maybe consider tagging the question with Spring or something …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `new APIResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK, banks)` instead of `new APIResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK, response)`? You do not have an `APIResponseEntity` constructor which takes a `List<>` as second argument defined.

Change your code to this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/banks", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public APIResponseEntity<List<Bank>> getBanks(WebRequest pWebRequest) {

    IUser user = getUser(pWebRequest);
    BankCriteria criteria = new BankCriteria();
    List<Bank> banks= _bankService.getBanks(user, criteria);
    APIResponse<List<Bank>> response = new APIResponse<>(banks);
    APIResponseEntity<List<Bank>> entity =  new APIResponseEntity<List<Bank>>(HttpStatus.OK, response); // errror , cannot infer type arguments for APIResponseEntity
    return entity;
}
```

Comment: I reconstructed the code above and compiled it, I think you're on the money.

Comment: if it works then you should also try to use this `new APIResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK, response);`. If the answer solved your question do not forget to mark it as accepted.